# Match words only starting with a certain letter and then having 5 or more non-whitespace characters

Tags: regex

I have tried following regex.

- `(?i)(^t|^d|^i|)\S{5}.*` - This matches any string regardless of starting char.
- `(?i)^(t|d|i|)\S{5}.*` - This matches only the one which start with char "t"
- `(?i)[tdi]\S{5}.*` - This looks good but unable to use ^ as this just negate. If i use `^` inside `(?i)[^tdi]\S{5}.*` then it matches everything except one which start with `t`. I want to match `txxxxx` but not `xtxxxx` and same is the case for `i` and `d`.

What is correct regex to achieve it?

First, string must start with one of these char specified and then must follow minimum 5 char (no whitespace) char and then it can have anything behind, i.e `txxxxx.domain.local`, `dxxxxx.domain.local` but at the same time it should not match with `xtxxxx.domain.local` or `xdxxxx.domain.local`.

Comment: Do you mean whole strings starting with `a`, `b` or `c`? Or words inside a string? What "words"? Is `a--++=` a word? Note in your first two examples, there is an extraneous `|`, last in the group, and the empty alternative makes the group optional, `(^t|^d|^i|)` = `((?:^t|^d|^i)?)`. Do you mean you just want `(?i)^[tdi]\S{5}.*`? But what do you write "This looks good but unable to use `^` as this just negate."?

Comment: If you want to match words starting with one of the listed in the character class, you can add `^` outside it to assert the start of the string `^[tdi]\S{5}(?!\S)` I think the first pattern matches the same as the second pattern.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the "before" and "after" that you're seeking?

Comment: Do you mean you just want (?i)^[tdi]\S{5}.* ? - yes if this works but it does not. it matches only string with start with char "t".

But what do you write "This looks good but unable to use ^ as this just negate."? if i use ^ inside (?i)[^tdi]\S{5}.* then it matches everything except one which start with "t".

i want to match txxxxx but not xtxxxx and same is the case for i and d.

Does this clarify?

Comment: Not much. So, you want to match at word boundary? Try `(?i)\b[tdi]\w*`

Comment: @PuneetLamba - first string must start with one of these char specified and then must follow minimum 5 char (no whitespace) char and then it can have anything behind.

i.e txxxxx.domain.local, dxxxxx.domain.local but at the same time it should not match with xtxxxx.domain.local or xdxxxx.domain.local

hope this clarifies.

Comment: So, `(?i)\b[tdi]\S{5,}`? `(?i)(?<!\S)[tdi]\S{5,}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thaks. (?i)\b[tdi]\S{5,}? and (?i)\b[tdi]\w* both works. I would read more in detail about word boundry as not used it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you need to match any word that consists of letters, digits or underscors starting with a specific letter you may use

```
(?i)\b[tdi]\w*
```

It will match `t`, `T`, `d`, `D`, `I` or `i` at a word boundary (`\b`)  and then any 0 or more letters, digits or underscores.

You may use

```
(?i)(?<!\S)[tdi]\S{5,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qYbJAB/1)

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier on
- `(?<!\S)` - whitespace should come right before the match
- `[tdi]` - one of the three letters that the word should start with
- `\S{5,}` - five or more non-whitespace chars.